# Program crashes when trying to set a character of a char array

Tags: c++, char

I got this weird behavior of my programm, that i cant figure out. My professor showed me a flaw in my programm, where i just copy a char pointer when i construct an object instead of making a new copy of the whole array, so you can fool around with it. He demonstrated this with similar code like this.

For the code:

```
char sweat[] ="Sweater";
warenkorb = new WareImKorb(new Textil (205366,4.2,sweat,40),2,warenkorb);
sweat[0] = '\0';
```

now if i instead make it:

```
char* sweat ="Sweater";
```

the program runs fine till i try sweat[0] = '\0';
It simply crahes then.

However this works:
    char cc[] ="Sweater";
    char* sweat = cc;

It is really bugging me, that i dont understand, why version 1 does not work.
Hope you guys can help me out, or else i will go crazy wondering about this.

Comment: What does not work about the first version? Why are you using char arrays instead of std::string?

Comment: Same question in C: [c - Why do I get a segmentation fault when writing to a "char *s" initialized with a string literal, but not "char s\[\]"? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164194/why-do-i-get-a-segmentation-fault-when-writing-to-a-char-s-initialized-with-a)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
char* sweat ="Sweater";
sweat[0] = '\0'
```

Here `sweat` points to a CONSTANT data. "Sweater" is const literal data, residing somewhere in read-only memory, and `sweat` points to this data as such. **It doesn't make a copy of it.** So when you do `sweat[0]='\0'`, it tries to change first character of the CONSTANT data. Hence the error. By the way, a good compiler should give warning if you don't write `const` in your declaration, as  `const char* sweater = "Sweater"`. See the warning here : http://www.ideone.com/P47vv

But when you write `char sweat[] = "Sweater"`, an array of char is created, copying the data from the CONSTANT data which is `"Sweater"`; that array's element itself is modifiable!

---

Lets see an interesting thing: since in the first case, it doesn't make a copy of the const data, so no matter how many variables you declare (all pointing to the same data), the address would be same for all variables. See this:

```
#include<cstdio>
int main() {
        char* sweat  ="Sweater";        //notice the warning
        const char* another ="Sweater"; //no warning!
        std::printf("%p\n", sweat);     //print the address
        std::printf("%p\n", another);   //print the address
        return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0x8048610
0x8048610
```

Means, both printfs print the same address!

See yourself here : http://www.ideone.com/VcyM6

Answer (score 5):

"Sweater" is a string literal, which may reside in read-only memory. Using the char[] syntax copies this literal into a char array, using the char * syntax (which really should be const char *) just points at the original string literal.

Answer (score 2):

ASCII art to the rescue! The `char sweat[]` version looks like this in memory:

```
       +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
sweat: |'S'|'w'|'e'|'a'|'t'|'e'|'r'| 0 |   char[8]
       +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Whereas the `char* sweat` version looks like this:

```
       +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
       |'S'|'w'|'e'|'a'|'t'|'e'|'r'| 0 |   const char[8]
       +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
         ^
         |
         |
       +-|-+
sweat: | | |   char*
       +---+
```

That's right, a `char*` pointing to a `const char`. The fact that you can assign a string literal to a non-const character pointer is a nasty holy in C++'s static type system. Curse you, backward compatibility!

Answer (score 0):

In the version that doesn't work, you are not creating any array of chars. You are only playing with pointers.

For `sweat[0] = '\0'` to be a valid statement, you need `sweat` to be an actual array of chars.

This is done only with `char sweat[] = "XXXX";` or `char sweat[20];`

Answer (score 0):

C++ is not a managed language.  Avoid creating pointers to character arrays that don't have a proper size.  Both of the following examples are better solutions:

```
char* sweater = new char[10];
sweater[0] = '\0';
delete [] sweater;
sweater = NULL;
```

Or better yet:

```
std::string sweater = "";
```